# Getting Windows 7 to join our LDAP domain

Tags: windows-7, ldap

I am trying to get my Windows 7 PC to join the LDAP domain (Samba). I have a bunch of computers that join correctly and that all works fine. I am now configuring a new computer to join the domain, but it doesn't work.

What I have tried:
Go to System settings

1. In Tab "Computer Name", I click "Change"
2. I update the computer name and select the domain (I checked with other PCs and the name is correct)
3. Click OK, I get my login screen for a user that can add computers
4. Click OK, and I get the message "The given domain does not exist or cannot contact it".

(I have a Dutch Windows, so the translations might not be verbatim to what an English Windows would say).

I know the network connection is OK, because internet works fine (am typing this question on said computer).

How can I get this computer on my domain?

Comment: Is the DNS of the computer properly set to an internal server, so the domain controller can be resolved?

Comment: Yes. I had to fix a few registry settings to get it working: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1330637 almost at the bottom. It works now.

Comment: Hey, sorry to pester you about this years later, but could I bother you to summarize and post your answer here?  I had a minor heart attack and mini-rant when something I wanted to do seemed to have an open question 5 years later, when the real answer was in the comments.

Comment: @Matthew_Sp it was indeed quite some time ago. I don't even know what my "fix" was (the ubuntu thread is quite long). You are free to post your answer and I'll accept.